# Database call clarification on rs.getString("columnName")

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdbc, resultset

we know using Jdbc driver we connect to DB , and rs.next() points to cursor , my question is when we read each columns data using rs.getString("position of column/name of the column),
My Question is , where is the data coming when we call rs.getXXX(...) is it calling db server every time we do rs.getXXX(...) or the entire row data already inside Results object?

if the db call happening for every column value to read, how to avoid this instead read all the row data and map column data by java application

Answer (score 0):

`JDBC` defines the concept of a [`fetch size`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize-int-) that controlls how many rows are *fetched* from the database to the client. The default size depend on the driver and RDBMS, but is typically greater than one.

This means that not even each `rs.next()` initiates a roundtrip to the database. Say if the fetch size is set to `10` only one of ten `rs.next()` will made a roundtrip to the database.

Consequently also all the `rs.getXXX` is *local action on the client* only